# A conjecture about $\mu(n)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, convergence-divergence, analytic-number-theory

Möbius function $\mu(n)$ is defined as $\mu(n) = (-1)^k$ when $n$ is square free and $n$ contains $k$ distinct prime factors, and 0 otherwise. Also $\mu(1)=1$. 
There are nice properties of this function like $$\sum_{d|n} \mu(d) = 0$$ unless $n=1$.

Let us consider $$S(x) = \sum_{n\leq x} \frac{\mu(n)}{n}$$
We see that $S(1)=1$ and $S(2) = \frac{1}{2}$ and so on.
What I observed by examples is $|S(x)| \leq 1$ for all $x$ and equality is satisfied only when $x=1$ but I am not able to prove or disprove this statement for any arbitrary $x$. If this is true then there is a possibility that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\mu(n)}{n}$ converges.

Comment: It is true, and $\sum \frac{\mu(n)}{n}$ converges (this fact is "equivalent" to the prime number theorem). Showing that $\lvert S(x)\rvert < 1$ for all $x \geqslant 2$ is easier. Do you know what Dirichlet convolution is?

Comment: It is true in fact that $\lim_{x\to\infty}S(x)=\lim_{s\to 1}\frac{1}{\zeta(s)}$

Comment: @Daniel Fischer I am not sure what is Dirchlet convolution, I will read about it

Comment: It's not essential, but it's a convenient way to see that $$\sum_{n \leqslant x} \mu(n)\biggl\lfloor \frac{x}{n}\biggr\rfloor = 1$$ for all $x \geqslant 1$. Another convenient way to see that is generalised Möbius inversion (which is a bit of a misnomer, because that is what Möbius' paper was about, so historically "ordinary Möbius inverson" would more accurately be called "specialised Möbius inversion").

Comment: This question is also a classic exercise that is often used in proofs of the equivilance of the convergence of the Mobius function and the PNT, see for example Tom Apostol's book Analytic Number Theory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in one of the comments $$\sum_{n \leq x} \mu(n) \left\lfloor \frac{x}{n} \right\rfloor = 1$$ is helpful in showing
your inequality is true.

Observe that

$$
1 = \sum_{n\leq x} \mu(n) \left\lfloor \frac{x}{n} \right\rfloor = 
\sum_{n\leq x} \mu(n) \left( \frac{x}{n} - \left\{ {\frac{x}{n}} \right\}\right) = 
xS(x) - \sum_{n\leq x} \mu(n) \left\{ {\frac{x}{n}} \right\} 
$$

where $\left\{ y \right\}$ is fractional part of $y$ which is always between 0 and 1.

So $$x|S(x)| \leq 1 + \sum_{n \leq x} \left\{ {\frac{x}{n}} \right\} \leq 1 + \left\{ x \right\}+  \sum_{2 \leq n \leq x} \left\{ {\frac{x}{n}} \right\} \le 1 + \left\{ x \right\}+ \lfloor x\rfloor -1 = x$$

Dividing by $x$ we get your strict inequality.